# AsyncTask not executiong in oncreate

Tags: android, image, download, android-asynctask

I'm Working in a project, I'm tring to download images from a folder, I have this code:

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<URL>, Integer, List<Bitmap>> {
    // Before the tasks execution
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Display the progress dialog on async task start
        mProgressDialog.show();
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
    }

    // Do the task in background/non UI thread
    protected List<Bitmap> doInBackground(ArrayList<URL>... urls) {
        int count = urls[0].size();
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        List<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();

        // Loop through the urls
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            URL currentURL = urls[0].get(i);
            // So download the image from this url
            try {
                // Initialize a new http url connection
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) currentURL.openConnection();

                // Connect the http url connection
                connection.connect();

                // Get the input stream from http url connection
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                // Initialize a new BufferedInputStream from InputStream
                BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

                // Convert BufferedInputStream to Bitmap object
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);

                // Add the bitmap to list
                bitmaps.add(bmp);

                // Publish the async task progress
                // Added 1, because index start from 0
                publishProgress((int) (((i + 1) / (float) count) * 100));
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    break;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                // Disconnect the http url connection
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        // Return bitmap list
        return bitmaps;
    }

    // On progress update
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // Update the progress bar
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    // On AsyncTask cancelled
    protected void onCancelled() {
        //Snackbar.make(mCLayout,"Task Cancelled.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // When all async task done
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Bitmap> result) {
        // Hide the progress dialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();


        // Loop through the bitmap list
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {

            Bitmap bitmap = result.get(i);
            saveToSdCard(bitmap,arrayID.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
}

// Custom method to convert string to url
protected URL stringToURL(String urlString) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        return url;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


public static String saveToSdCard(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {
    String stored = null;
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File folder = new File(sdcard.getAbsoluteFile(), "/imagens");
    folder.mkdir();
    File file = new File(folder.getAbsoluteFile(), filename);

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        stored = "success";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stored;
}
```

And I start this process using a button click like this:

```
mButtonDo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Execute the async task

            ArrayList<URL>arrayURL=new ArrayList<URL>();

            for (Integer i:arrayID)
            {
                URL url = stringToURL(getString(R.string.link)+i.toString()+".jpg");
                arrayURL.add(url);
            }

            mMyTask = new DownloadTask().execute(arrayURL);
        }
    });
```

And it works as I want too. But the problem now is that I want that this process is automatic and do when the Activity is started, so I putted this code in the OnCreate method:

```
ArrayList<URL>arrayURL=new ArrayList<URL>();

            for (Integer i:arrayID)
            {
                URL url = stringToURL(getString(R.string.link)+i.toString()+".jpg");
                arrayURL.add(url);
            }

            mMyTask = new DownloadTask().execute(arrayURL);
```

But it won't do anything, with the button click it starts fine, but in the OnCreate method it wont do anything, do anyone know how to solve this issue?
Thanks for your help and time.

**EDITED**
And have this code to fill my **arrayID**:

```
 public void BuscarIdProduto_Imagens()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            String SOAP_ACTION = "http://p4.com/BuscarIdProdutos";
            String METHOD_NAME = "BuscarIdProdutos";


            //Criar um Pedido SOAP
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            //Parametrização do SOAP
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);


            //O envelope SOAP que se associa ao pedido
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            //Classe: Indicar como o Servidor de WS pode ser alcançado
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            try{
                //SOAP Request(Pedido)
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);


                //IR buscar a Resposta que me foi enviado pelo Servidor de WS
                SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

                if (response.getPropertyCount() > 0) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.getPropertyCount(); i++) {

                        SoapPrimitive soapObject = ((SoapPrimitive) response.getProperty(i));
                        //instanciar    o   canal   de  output

                        arrayID.add(Integer.valueOf(soapObject.toString()));
                    }
                }

                System.out.println();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("------------------------------>" + ex.toString());
            }

        }
    }).start();
}
```

I debuged the program and I think the KSOAP finish with his thread after the AsyncTask starts, and that can not be possivel because I need the array filled, is there some way to start the asynctask after the ksoap thread is finish?

Comment: `onCreate` method of Activity or Fragment? If you are using fragment, it is better to put in the `onActivityCreated`

Comment: it's a `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Do you try to debug?

Comment: @LiemVo I changed my question, thanks.

Comment: Do you call this method `BuscarIdProduto_Imagens()` in `onCreate` as well?

Comment: @Yupi yes i call in oncreate as well

Comment: @LauraSaraiva then I think problem is simple calling `synchronous` code which is actually `asynchronous`. If you need more details I will post an answer.

Comment: @Yupi I didn't undersand very well, could you then please post an answer, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from your code snippets I assume that problem is calling both methods in `onCreate` but both methods do network calls. So basically when you call this part of code:

```
ArrayList<URL>arrayURL=new ArrayList<URL>();

for (Integer i:arrayID) {
     URL url = stringToURL(getString(R.string.link)+i.toString()+".jpg");
     arrayURL.add(url);
   }

mMyTask = new DownloadTask().execute(arrayURL);
```

In this case `arrayID` didn't get values yet and probably `for` loop is skipped and an empty `list` or `arrayURL` is passed to the `AsyncTask`. That will also answer why code works on `onClick` because meanwhile `arrayID` is populated with data from network.

So what you want is to make sure that `arrayID` is populated with data before you call part of code which I pasted above. So create an `interface` inside your `Activity` for example:

```
 public interface OnDataFetched {
   void fetchSuccess(ArrayList<URL> arrayID);
 }
```

Now go to your `Activity` and `implement` this `interface` and `override` method `fetchSuccess`:

```
public class YourAcitivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnDataFetched
...

@Override
public void fetchSuccess(ArrayList<URL> arrayID) {

}
```

After that in same `Activity` create a field:

```
private OnDataFetched onDataFetched;
```

Inside `onCreate`:

```
onDataFetched = this;
```

After that go into your  `BuscarIdProduto_Imagens` method after `for` loop:

```
if (response.getPropertyCount() > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < response.getPropertyCount(); i++) {

                    SoapPrimitive soapObject = ((SoapPrimitive) response.getProperty(i));
                    //instanciar    o   canal   de  output

                    arrayID.add(Integer.valueOf(soapObject.toString()));
                }
             if(onDataFetched != null)
                onDataFetched.fetchSuccess(arrayID);
     }
```

And the last thing move `AsyncTask` code inside ovirrieded `fetchSuccess`:

```
@Override
public void fetchSuccess(ArrayList<URL> arrayID) {
for (Integer i:arrayID) {
     URL url = stringToURL(getString(R.string.link)+i.toString()+".jpg");
     arrayURL.add(url);
    }
    mMyTask = new DownloadTask().execute(arrayURL);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but, there is a problem, I debuged the program and in this line **mMyTask = new DownloadTask().execute(arrayURL);** it gives this error: **java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[Thread-2,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()** I already tried move the code outside the threat but its is not possível becouse it must be in a thread, do you have any idea how to fix this? thank you so far for your help.

Comment: @LauraSaraiva Ah yes code is running inside new `Thread` so basically the solution is to create a `callback` with interface. I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the aswerd but I continuo to have the same error I created a git repository with that 2 files so you can have a cleaner way to view the code: [link](https://github.com/LauraSaraiva/ImageDownload)

Comment: @LauraSaraiva I'm unable to open up this url: http://192.168.1.6:8080/WS_produtos/WS_produtos so I can not test the code

Comment: that url is a webservice writen in java using netbeans, I have updated my git repository and now is there the android code, the webservice and the mysql backup.

Comment: @LauraSaraiva okay I will take a look

Comment: Hi, sorry disturbing you but have you find any solution? Thanks

Comment: @LauraSaraiva Hi no problem, I was unable to run your project can you push whole project, seems like some files are missing: gradle files etc

Comment: Here is the link : [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e5625cf65b3bc5e7954ac75581191f9520190926145408/6bbaba)

Comment: @LauraSaraiva any chance you can zip it like .zip this is .rar file which I can not open on Mac? Sorry

Comment: [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/44af64965f1c1e8f0c5be6dbd0f5db2220190929211915/01aa04)

Comment: @LauraSaraiva not sure why I can not run your server code. I suppose you used Eclipse for it or?

Comment: Hello, I use NetBeans